# best way to handle fixed padding and flexible width/height

Tags: css, height, padding

Lets say

```
.container{
   padding:25px;
   height:100%;
}
```

So here `.container` would be 100%+25px height.

A problem would be when, for example:

```
.container{
       padding:25px;
       height:100%;
       float:left;
    }
 .noPadding{ padding:0px;}


<body>
    <div class="container">blah</div>
    <div class="container noPadding">bleh</div>
</body>
```

They both have height 100% but one will be bigger.

So how can I make them the same size and keep padding? I don't know how much would be 100%-25*2px... it depends on screen resolution.

Comment: JavaScript is typically used in these situations to calculate actual size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the pretty JS library **jQuery** to achieve that!
look:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LjYpN/)

```
$('.noPadding').height( $('.container:eq(0)').outerHeight(true) );
```

To calculate the first .conteiner height (with paddings) you can use: `.outerHeight(true)`
and than just pass it to the `.height()` of your .noPadding element!

---

More info:

[jQuery API .outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)
[jQuery API .height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `box-sizing` property for this:

```
.container{
       padding:25px;
       height:100%;
       float:left;
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
       -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

Check this article for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Please someone say IE is no more :(

Comment: May be you have to check this for IE7 support http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201104/controlling_width_with_css3_box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 100% in CSS doesn't really do anything. You will notice removing it likely will not change the size of the element in question. Now, the only way to create two elements of the same height when the size can be dynamic is through javascript. You'll want to get the height of the first one and then apply it to the second element.

an example would be

```
var height = document.getElementById('element1').height;
document.getElementById('element2').height = height;
```

Comment: False: if parent is 100% aswell it does do work; thanks for your js code